# Powershell printer hot folder - Specific printer and then delete file

Tags: powershell, printing, hotfolder

I'm trying to achieve the following process in a powershell script as we need the device's default printer to one thing (small QR code label generated in Chrome) and a specific label (PDF from shipping API) to be printed on another printer:

1. PDF file of shipping label is saved to a hot folder
2. PDF file of shipping label prints to specific printer
3. PDF file of shipping label is then deleted
4. QR code label can just be Ctrl+P as normal as the device's default printer is already set correctly

I've found a couple of scripts which I was looking to "Frankenstein's monster" to what I need but thought I'd ask for advice first!

The 2 scripts/snippets I found:

The loop for printing from a specific folder

```
$files = Get-ChildItem "c:\shipping\*.pdf"

foreach ($file in $files){
    start-process -FilePath $file.fullName -Verb Print
}
```

And, for selecting the correct printer

`Get-Content -Path "$root\UNB\FINAL_TEXTO\$archivo" | Out-Printer -Name (Get-Printer | Where-Object {$_.Name -like "UNBILLING"}.Name`

Print from hot folder